# StackOverFlowError on setting label Java

Tags: java

I have a function which calculates value in double. When I print it using `System.err.println(amt_without_tax)` then I get `1334.0` as output then I convert double to string using:

```
String s = Double.toString(amt_without_tax);
System.err.println(s);
```

and then set text to label using:

```
lblTotalAmount.setText(s);
```

But it gives:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3797)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3798)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3461)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1248)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:664)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2549)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1191)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setText(JLabel.java:330)
at view.InvoiceBak.calculateSumAll(InvoiceBak.java:1198)
at view.InvoiceBak.lblTotalAmountPropertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:640)
at view.InvoiceBak.access$800(InvoiceBak.java:40)
at view.InvoiceBak$10.propertyChange(InvoiceBak.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
```

I have tried many times but unable to get rid of this problem on setting text to label. Please help.

Comment: You don't appear to be showing the source of the problem ,and until you do, I think that this question will remain unanswered.

Comment: @which line is `InvoiceBak.java:1191`?

Comment: What is `lblTotalAmount`? Can you post more code and let us know which line is exactly throwing up the error

Comment: Do you have any ChangedListener for the label?

Comment: Ah a PropertyChangeListener

Comment: @AntonyDao thanks for response. There is recusrion due to ChangedListener having call to same function which change the value of label.  thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You are welcome! J